# SubView Does not come to front after rotation

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uibutton, rotation

I have a subView which takes rotation and then i have to move it to front of a view.

Let me moreclear ...

I have a subView Button say Button1.

and i have rotate it using following methods

```
[myButton.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0, 1, 0)];
```

and then

```
[myButton.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(2*M_PI, 0, 1, 0)];
```

Now when i clicked to it, it has to add a UIImageView as a subview to the main View, and then move to the top(i mean the button needs to be in front of the ImageView).
for that i have used following method

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myButton];
```

But this is not working for me...

the button remains always backside to that image view
i also tried to send that imageView to back but that also not working...

I hope you understand the question......

Comment: How and when you add the image view would greatly affect the order of display. Could you give more information about it?

Comment: @ChinaPaul- after animation when user click that button....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is conceptually related to this question, try to make the second rotation from 2*M_PI to 0.

```
[myButton.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, 1, 0)];
```

and leave rest of the code as it is